# How to change placeholder in Material Color not using deep?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to change placeholder for inputs in Material Color not using deep and important and using global approach?

Is it possible to pass custom variable to existing angular theme to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of basic CSS for doing this.
For example,

```css
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="A red placeholder text..">
```